# Our css3 menu doesn't work in IE10. It works in FF and Chrome. Is it an HTML5 issue?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

We have a graphic that doesn't render properly in IE10. It was working fine and then about a month ago, it quit working on IE10 but continues to display properly on Chrome and Firefox. I've read that HTML5 does not work properly with IE10. Is that the issue? Not sure of the fix.

```
 <table width=""  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td   width="220" valign="top">
 <div class="menu">

  <!--#if expr="${REMOTE_HOST} = /.usgs.gov$/" -->
  <a href="http://internal.usgs.gov/ngp"><b>NGP Intranet</b></a>
  <!--#endif -->
  <p>
  <!--#include virtual="include/tnm_menu.html"-->
  </div>

  <!--<p class="space"></p> --><br class="space" />

  <img src="images/nav_spacer.jpg" width="185" height="1700" border="0"      alt="This is a formatting graphic." />
  </td>
```

Comment: Create a http://jsfiddle.net (or something similar) to help visualise your issue.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle.net link:  http://jsfiddle.net/pamfromoz/xzcL7g04/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include any links to external images, it also doesn't match the structure of the code you provided above. Ie. There is no `img` tag in the HTML code in the fiddle. What is the actual issue? You say it "doesn't render properly", but how do you expect it to render. Fix the fiddle so it displays the problem.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. There are two issues... First, a formatting graphic doesn't render properly in IE10. It's supposed to fill in green space under the menu. Instead, it is skewed. It used to work up until a month ago. See the fiddle html code. Secondly, the css menu does not display properly in IE10. Code works fine in FF and Chrome.  Website:  http://nationalmap.gov/  Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pamfromoz/xzcL7g04/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website you provided, not the fiddle as it is still pretty pointless as it doesn't replicate the issue at all, you can fix the "skewed" green space by adding to the CSS:

```
#nav {
    padding:0;
}
```

For the other problem of the CSS menu, and possibly the above problem, I believe this is due to the HTML code being completely invalid. There are so many problems with the code that it doesn't know how to render it correctly. Give it a quick pass through a validator and you will see some errors. Firstly, you are using HTML5 elements, but declared the DOCTYPE as XHTML. And that's just the start, you have unclosed tags, obsolete attributes, unescaped characters, plus others.

The reason why this is a problem is that when using `position:absolute` the browser looks for the parent of the element but if it can't work it out, it could position the element anywhere. FF and Chrome work because they are less strict than IE over this, and I think this is an issue with FF and Chrome, they try to "fix" what the developer has done, but in my opinion this just breeds lazy and bad development.

Fix the issues, especially the unclosed tags, and it should help. (At least help narrow down the issue.)